# Measure of the intersection of a decreasing sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

In Donald Cohn's Measure Theory book, in part (b) of Proposition 1.2.5 he states that if $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space, and $\{ A_k \}$ is a decreasing sequence of sets in $\Sigma$, and there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\mu(A_n) < \infty$, then $\mu(\cap_k A_k) = lim_k \mu(A_k)$. In the exercises section he then shows that this equality is not necessarily true if we don't have the $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ for some $n$. And my intuition (that i've mostly gotten from solving the exercise) tells me that this is because we can have a decreasing sequence of sets, that all have infinite measure, but their intersection is either empty or has finite measure. Are there any non trivial examples of this happening, and can this happen if we take $X = \mathbb{R}$, $\Sigma = M_{\lambda^*}$ (the set of all the lebesgue measurable subsets) and $\mu = \lambda$, the lebesgue measure?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by a non-trivial example? Any example must be such that each $A_k$ has infinite measure, and such that the intersection $A=\bigcap A_k$ has finite measure.

Comment: Something on the $(\mathbb{R}, M_{\lambda}, \mu)$ measure space would be interesting, because i don't know how to construct it there.

Comment: For an example in $\Bbb{R}$, look at $A_k=[k,\infty)$; this is a decreasing sequence, with empty intersection. If you want something with non-empty intersection, take any finite-measure set $E\subset (-\infty,0)$, and let $A_k=E\cup[k,\infty)$. Then, each $A_k$ has infinite measure, it's a decreasing sequence, and the intersection is $E$ which has finite measure.

Comment: thanks! This was helpful